# How to use RocksDB for HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, rocksdb

I'm writing a Spark application running on HDFS, the output is an RDD, which I have to save to RocksDB. But I don't know how to get RocksDB to work with HDFS and Spark. Please give me some instructions on how to set up RocksDB on HDFS and integrate it with Spark

We have gone to the website 
https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/tree/master/hdfs but we cannot find hdfs.h and libhdfs so we don't know how to proceed.

```scala
var sq = Seq[RDD[(String, Array[String])]]()
for (file <- files) {
     val filename = file.getPath.toString()

     val lines = sc.textFile(filename)
     val doc_id = filename.split("/").last.dropRight(4) 
     val key_value = lines.flatMap(_.split(" ")).map(word => (word, Array((doc_id)))).reduceByKey((a,b) => a)
     sq = sq :+ key_value
} 
     val output = sc.union(sq)
     output.reduceByKey((a,b) => a ++ b) // this is the output RDD that we need to save to RocksDB
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work for that branch or RocksDB, but you can find hdfs.h and libhdfs.so in any hadoop distribution.

E.g. for Cloudera CDH they are under /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/include and /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib64.

The source code is here: https://github.com/apache/hadoop-hdfs/tree/trunk/src/c%2B%2B/libhdfs

Let me know if you managed to compile RocksDB with HDFS, and how it works?